# Python tkinter using variables and user input from GUI to run code

Tags: python, pandas, file, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd

def retrieve_input():
    file = textBox.get("1.0","end-1c")
    basefileread = pd.read_csv(str(textBox) + '.csv', encoding='latin-1')
    basefilevalue = basefileread.loc[basefileread['Customer'].str.contains('Lam DepT', na=False),'Jun-18\nQty']


master = Tk()
master.geometry('200x100')

textBox = Text(master, height=2, width=10)
textBox.pack()

button1 = Button(master,text="Get Value", command=lambda: retrieve_input())
button1.pack()

master.mainloop()

print(int(textBox)+10)
```

I am trying to extract the information that I place into a textbox and run the following code, I want to specify which csv file I want the program to read, and find the value I specified from that file. I tried to hard code in textbox in my pandas reader and am just having trouble extraxting the string information that I type in the GUI and have that string appear so it can run my code. I am unsure if I am articulating my question correctly. And when I run this I get the error:

```
 FileNotFoundError: File b'.!text.csv' does not exist
```

Comment: You need to move the pandas code into the retrive_input function, so it gets run when button is clicked. That function also needs whatever you want to do with the data, I assume print it or add it to a widget for display.

Comment: @Novel Okay, thank you, however I did try that before and got the error that is posted now in my edited question so I though that was the wrong way to do it. Any idea why I am getting this error?

Comment: You want to load the name that you saved to the variable "file". So `basefileread = pd.read_csv(file+'.csv', encoding='latin-1')`. Also remember to add a print or something so you see the result.

Comment: Unrelated, but that lambda function is useless. Just pass the function to be executed directly. `button1 = Button(master,text="Get Value", command=retrieve_input)`

Comment: @Novel It worked perfectly! Thank you for your help, means alot.

Comment: @Novel okay I will edit my code accordingly, thanks again!

Comment: I recommend you delete this post since it's a syntactic error on your part. Also, you may be better off in the future with a more beginner oriented forum such as learnpython.reddit.com.

Comment: @Novel Okay I will do so, the original question was not synthatic however. Also this is a test code for my actual program which has almost 1000 lines of "pandas code" would I have to put all of that code within this function then?

Comment: @Novel Also do you think its fine to leave this question because it might provide sudo code and a base to look at for people who are attempting to run the same type of program but run into small syntactic errors which prevents them for running this code.

Comment: Yes. Hopefully your 1000 lines is not all at root level. If it is start learning about separating logical blocks of code into functions, classes and modules. Good code has no code at root level.

Comment: @Novel lol I don't even know what root level means, but that advice is good! Thank you, and yes I am a begginer so perhaps that reddit forum would be a better use of peoples times. Thank you!

Comment: This site is more for high level programming questions, not for fixing beginner level syntactic mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem lies within the `retriece input()` function
you retrieve the text into the variable `file`, yet use `str(textBox)` to read the file

solution should work like this

```
def retrieve_input():
    file = textBox.get("1.0","end-1c")
    basefileread = pd.read_csv(file +'.csv', encoding='latin-1')
    basefilevalue = basefileread.loc[basefileread['Customer'].str.contains('Lam DepT', na=False),'Jun-18\nQty'
```

Comment: Lol, karma thief.

Comment: Answerong simultaneosly is  the stuff, sry °_°^